# Create a Windows process to check silently for missing DLLs

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, process

I want to check if all the required DLLs are installed for an executable, so I run it with `CreateProcess`, and I check the exit code.

Problem: Windows displays a popup saying the DLL was not found, then displays a popup saying that the program has stopped working.

How can I avoid all these error popups?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call [`SetErrorMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680621%28VS.85%29.aspx) passing `SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS`.

The `SetErrorMode` is a slightly tricky API to use since you need to merge the new mode with the existing modes. Raymond Chen [explains how to do it correctly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/27/198410.aspx).

Comment: SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS only disables the first error window, but with SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS | SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX it also disable the Windows Error Reporting dialog !

Comment: OK, sounds like you are well on top of things!

Comment: Now you no longer have any idea what DLL is missing.

Comment: @Hans: my exe only depends on DirectX DLLs, so if I detect that some DLLs are missing, I can tell the user that he must install/update DirectX.

Comment: DirectX uses COM objects, which are loaded dynamically at runtime. Your EXE should not be statically linking to the DLLs directly, but let the OS load the DLLs dynamically when needed. In which case, the EXE can do its own run-time checks to make sure DirectX is installed and has the needed functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway this won't cover all the problematic cases. Your process may be dependent on delay-load DLLs. You may check your executable by the [dependency walker tool](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) (or similar).

However your process may try to load more DLLs at runtime (via `LoadLibrary` or similar).

Comment: I know I can do that, but I want to deploy this on customer computers and display a user friendly message.